# Validate Current Document Option Unavailable

Tags: validation, dreamweaver

I am using DreamWeaver for development and I want to validate a website. I have followed a tutorial that said,
[image]

Now when I attempted step 5, it is not highlighting the Validate Current Document option to be used. Can anyone please help me out why would this option be unavailable?

Answer (score 1):

The Validation options are [in the process of being deprecated and removed](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2817700) starting with CS5 and the only validation that is still supported is XML.  In other words, use the W3C tool to validate.

If you follow the link to the Adobe support discussion above you will be able to download an extension that adds the functionality back in.